# How to get all files from a folder using *

Tags: c#

I have this code and it works.

```cs
msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Server.MapPath("~/myPdf/toAllInterns/IT_KFMC_Training_Plan_2023.pdf")));
```

I do not want to specify the file name, I want to get all PDF files or all Word files or any other file extension. I used * instead of a file name like *.pdf. it caused me an error

What is the right code to get all files from the folder?

```cs
msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Server.MapPath("~/myPdf/toAllInterns/*.pdf")));
```

gave me an error. I was expecting to get all pdf files into the attachment.

Comment: You could build a string array using Directory.GetFiles(), then add each element as an attachment.

Comment: Use the *correct* method. `Server.MapPath` maps paths, it doesn't search directories. Use the correct method, eg `Directory.GetFile` or `Directory.EnumerateFiles` then add attachments one by one

Comment: `get all pdf files into the attachment.` that's a bit unclear. An attachment is a single file. You can either add multiple attachments, one for each file. Or you can create and attach a ZIP file containing all the PDFs.

Comment: Google returns the necessary method for "c# get all files from folder". Why you ask here and not tried to find it (from first link)?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way:

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo("pathtoyourfolder");
FileInfo[] files = info.GetFiles("*.pdf");
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?